# Confused about javascript function returning multiple functions with many fat arrow

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, closures, currying

I have problem with my cs homework. 
I need to access the `x` value of the function, but my codes is returning me an empty function instead of with the values

I have googled all the currying and closures, but none of them are advanced enough to help me solve my problem

```
const pair = (x, y) => f => f(x, y);  // Do not edit this function
const head = p => //Answer here                

console.log(head(pair(1,2)))          // Do not edit this
```

my console keeps returning me `functions` instead when I try all the combinations

`function(a,b){return a;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change `head` function like this:

```js
const pair = (x, y) => f => f(x, y); 
const head = f => f(a => a)

console.log(head(pair(1,2)))
```

Comment: @Peter here, `pair` is executed before `head`. You can add `console.log()` to check it.

Comment: @Peter saw your edit to the question now. Updated `head`

Comment: @Peter I didn't get you. *"pass in function as a params*" where?

Comment: @ adiga I don't get the f(a=> a) part after looking at it for a super long time

Comment: `a => a` is an arrow function just like `(x, y) => f`. You  can write it like `(a, b) => a` if it's too confusing

Comment: I understand `(x,y) => f` but I do not understand `f => f(a,b => a `  is it taking in a `function f` then opening `f` which contains params `(a,b)`?

Answer (score 1):

> my console keeps returning me this instead
>
> `function(a,b){return a;}`

Let's make this easier to read. In ES5, your code looks like this:

```
var pair = function(x, y) {
  return function(f) {
    return f(x, y);
  }
};

var head = function(p) {
  return function(a, b) {
    return a;
  }
};
```

You need to pass the function returned from `head` to the function returned by `pair(1, 2)`. So you need to swap which order you're calling the functions in:

```
console.log(pair(1, 2)(head()));
```

Comment: Then swap the logic in each function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly or not but I guess you are trying to do this

```js
const pair = (x, y) => f => f(x, y); 
const head = (x, y) => x;

console.log((pair(1,2)(head)))
```

if not then this one from above is correct

```js
const pair = (x, y) => f => f(x, y); 
const head = f => f(a => a);

console.log(head(pair(1,2)))
```

Comment: What does this add? Both of these are already mentioned in the answers above

Comment: First one is not same as above but second one yes. I was unable to comment their so mentioned that point here.